# Combine sequence of asynchronous requests to build final answer

Tags: node.js, express

I'm rather new in express framework. I have call flickr api to get albums list and for each album need to get its thumbnail. On the end need to build `covers` array with list of objects like `{title, thumb}`. I would like to pass fully created `covers` array to template and render. I have problem with it because of the way that node.js callbacks works and *for loop* ends quickly before requests ends. How to do that properly ?

```
http.get(base_url+'&user_id='+flickr.user_id+'&method=flickr.photosets.getList', function(resp){
    var body = '';
    resp.on('data', function(chunk) {
        body += chunk;
    });
    resp.on('end', function() {
        var json = JSON.parse(body);
        var ps = json.photosets.photoset;

        // final answer
        var covers = {};

        for(var i=0; i<ps.length; i++) {
            var p = ps[i];
            var getSizesUrl = base_url+'&user_id='+flickr.user_id+'&method=flickr.photos.getSizes&photo_id='+p.primary;
            http.get(getSizesUrl, function(resp){
                var body1 = '';
                resp.on('data', function(chunk) {
                    body1 += chunk;
                });
                resp.on('end', function() {
                    var json1 = JSON.parse(body1);
                    covers += {title: p.title._content, thumb: json1.sizes.size[1].source};

                   if(i + 1 == ps.length) {
                        // last call
                        console.log(covers);
                        res.render('photosets', {covers: covers});
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Update using `async` and `request` as @sgwilly said, but something wrong...

```
request(base_url+'&user_id='+flickr.user_id+'&method=flickr.photosets.getList', function (error, response, body) {
    var json = JSON.parse(body);
    var ps = json.photosets.photoset;

    // functions list to call by `async`
    var funcs = {};

    for(var i = 0; i < ps.length; i++) {
        var p = ps[i];
        funcs += function(callback) {
            request(base_url+'&user_id='+flickr.user_id+'&method=flickr.photos.getSizes&photo_id='+p.primary, function (error, response, body1){
                var json1 = JSON.parse(body1);
                var cover = {title: p.title._content, thumb: json1.sizes.size[1].source};
                callback(null, cover);
            });         
        };
    }

    // run requests and produce covers
    async.series(funcs,
        function(covers){
            console.log(covers);
            res.render('photosets', {covers: covers});              
        }
    );

});
```

Comment: Have you tried using the [request](https://npmjs.org/package/request) and [async](https://npmjs.org/package/async) modules ? They can do most of the heavy lifting for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node.js callbacks are a little tricky, but they'll make sense after a while.

You want to use [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) as your outside loop, then [async.concat](https://github.com/caolan/async#concat) as a callback inside, and have each iterator be a request call of a URL.

Comment: Thank You very much! This was a hint that I was looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for @dankohn. I got this and work :)

```
request(base_url+'&user_id='+flickr.user_id+'&method=flickr.photosets.getList', function (error, response, body) {
    var json = JSON.parse(body);
    var ps = json.photosets.photoset;

    async.concat(ps, function(p, callback){
        request(base_url+'&user_id='+flickr.user_id+'&method=flickr.photos.getSizes&photo_id='+p.primary, function (error, response, body1){
            var json1 = JSON.parse(body1);
            var cover = {title: p.title._content, thumb: json1.sizes.size[1].source};
            callback(null, cover);
        });         
    }, 
    function(err, covers){
        console.log(covers);
        res.render('photosets', {covers: covers});          
    });
});
```